# Why does my game crash once while loop is run (Pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

my code:

```
def shop_button(self):
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if click[0] == 1:
        self.open_shop()  # draws shop
        self.inshop = True
        while self.inshop:
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if click[0] == 1 and b.mouse_on_button(mousepos[0], mousepos[1], b.escapex, b.escapex2, b.escapey, b.escapey2):
                self.inshop = False
```

whenever you click on the shop button this function is run, however, while self.inshop is inside an if statement like such the game instantly stops responding and crashes. This could be a very simple solution as I am semi-new to pygame and the python language as a whole. However, with that being said I can't seem to find a solution anywhere else.

Comment: how do you know that the program crashes?

Answer (score 1):

The game does not crash, it does not respond, because you have a loop inside the main application loop. The inner loop has no event handling and update of the display.

> ```py
> def shop_button(self):
>    # [...]
>
>    while self.inshop:
>            pygame.time.delay(10)
>            mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
>            # [...]
> ```

The position which is returned by [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) is read from an internal cache. The cache is updated when the events are handled by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
That means if you retrieve the position in a loop, without handling the events, the the position does not reflect the current mouse position, it is continuously the same position, the position at the point when `pygame.event.get()` called, before the loop.
Furthermore the display [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) won't change, without updating the display, by either [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) or [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update).

You have a main application loop, use it. The main application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Never implemented nested application loops. You have to change the control flow and the design of your applcaition.